# How can I set a custom font for the action bar text, and make it happen from startup?

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar

I can't get it done. My App starts with the standard font, the custom activity layout is inflated, and just then my font changes. As far as I know, I cannot directly code a custom font into the xml file of the layout I intend to inflate onto the action bar, so I got a code from another topic on the net about doing the change by referencing the TextView in the action bar and setting it in the class. Is there actually a way to make the font "standard", so that the app will already startup showing my custom font?

Here is the relevant code for the main activity, which I'm trying to change:

```
    public class Amd extends Activity {

    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    public ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public JSONObject jsonOb;
    public Filme m;
    public ArrayList<Genero> g;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.amd);
        setActionBar();
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") private void setActionBar(){
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "tcb.ttf");
        TextView textoActionBar = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android"));
        textoActionBar.setTypeface(font);
        textoActionBar.setText("TESTE");
        this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    }
```

Here is the styles xml, which I am also using to theme and color the action bar:

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/PurpleActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PurpleActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#5D4480</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#975CE6</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.virosys.amd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.virosys.amd.activities.Amd"
            android:label="AMD"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the layout I'm inflating to the main activity:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/Purple"
    tools:context="com.virosys.amd.activities.Amd" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:onClick="listasOuFilmes"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/filmes" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:onClick="buscarFilme"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/busca" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:onClick="inserirFilme"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/noimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/config" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What else should I need to specify, or do you need any other code to understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well, you cannot set a "standard" font, but does it really take that much time to inflate your layout that font change becomes noticeable?

Comment: What if you try moving "font changing" method before layout inflating? Shouldn't produce any error, and will make the transition less noticeable.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, I will try this out, If I haven't already tried. I got a lot of errors trying different methods, so...

Comment: @Android777 I actually tested what you hinted, there were no errors, but it didn't made a change at all. Thanks for your help and time anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since Android ActionBar `setTitle` method receives a `CharSequence` as a parameter you can simply replace the call of your `setActionBar()` method with the next lines, that using span:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "tcb.ttf");
String actionBarTitle = "TESTE";
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(actionBarTitle);
ssb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, actionBarTitle.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
getActionBar().setTitle(ssb);
```

And don't forget to add this custom typeface span class into your project.

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your code, and the behavior kept the same. The app loads my custom layout which paints the action bar with my own color, and then after loading the activity layout, it finally changes the typeface to my own. A cool end on this is that I actually managed to change the text itself, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use custom layout, just create a span with custom font and set it as a title.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to customize the action bar. I am doing it via a xml style, but I cannot assign custom fonts in the xml. Is there any other way to change the action bar's background color pre-startup?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a custom class that extends TextView, then within the constructor set your default font. Then reference that custom textview in your xml instead of Androids TextView.